# How to recover factory reset in iPhone 5 apps without backup

Tags: itunes, ios, applications, backup

I forget my passcode and when I reset my phone I lost all my data, photos and apps. I was connecting to iTunes but I never backed up.

How can I get all my photos and apps on my iPhone 5 without a back up?

I was able to restore my apps from iTunes, but its like new again, how can I include the data inside the applications?

Comment: The whole point of a backup is that it allows you to get back everything, if you haven't done this then I don't know how you intend on getting your data.

Answer (score 1):

But if you have a apple ID you can get apps back by simply downloading them on device with no extra fee

Answer (score 0):

Since you have NO back up there is no place where your data could come from (they are lost).

Sorry, but next time do a back up before doing stuff like Factory reset.